# html text whitespace below characters

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, whitespace

I am trying to make a mobile webpage using jquery mobile.

I have some strange behaviour with text inside a div or table cell with a background color.
It displays some whitespace below the characters, like the character is displyaed higher than it should be.

It is a bit hard to explain, the following screenshot shows the problem:
[image: screenshot whitespace]

My markup is as following:

```
<td width='50%' style='background-color: #626A99;'> 
<h3>1 DAY ACCESS FOR ONLY 9</h3>
</td>
```

**Solved**
Özkan ÖZLÜ got me on the right track.

To disable the shadow in jquery mobile, add the following below where the jquery mobile css is included:

```
 body .ui-body-d, body .ui-overlay-d { text-shadow: none; }
```

The letter d, has to be replaced with the theme that is used.

Comment: could be margin, padding or other. Please show some CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the shadow effect of `h3`. Try this:

```
<td width='50%' style='background-color: #626A99;'> 
<h3 style="text-shadow:none;">1 DAY ACCESS FOR ONLY 9</h3>
</td>
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3MUx/)

Comment: The text-shadow to none solved the problem. Have to see if I can do that somewhere for the entire page.